# Can't get references from project P1 to P2

Tags: c#, asp.net, reference

I have solution with 2 project P1 is main project with all function ,constatnsNames,references..... when i build P2 i set `refereces--Add reference---From project P1`  , after this i see all classes and all function ,but the reference from P1 is not in P2 sow when i try to use-

```
using WatiN.Core;
using WatiN.Core.Native;
```

in P2,it is not working unlit i dont add reference of WatIn to P2,but i all ready have this reference in P1.

Sow what i doing wrong?How can i use the references from P1 in P2?

> All projects set to 4.5 and Any CPU

Comment: You have specific reference DLL in p1 project and you want to use them in p2 by adding reference to P1. If this is what you want then it is not done automatic. You have to add reference from those DLL in P2 as well.

Comment: `Watin.Core` and `WatiN.Core.Native`. Which one is P1 and which one P2? Did you try cleaning and rebuilding the solution?

Edit: OK. As @dotnetstep said, you don't import the references in other project if you at it as a reference to this project.

Comment: Hmmmm...sow the reference to P1 will NOT give my the ddl's of P1?I will get only the finctions and classes from P1?

Comment: Yes. you can see P1 Project class and function but if you try to execute it or build project P2 it gives to error because other reference is missing.